# Check for multiple value pairs in dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a way to shorten this code?

I want to print something if either `a, b`, `a-foo, b-foo` or `a-bar, b-bar` are in the dic. Consider `-foo` and `-bar` to be fixed values.

Is there a concise way to check this in a single if-statement?

The dict looks like this:

```
defaultdict(<class 'set'>, {'key1': {'elem1', 'elem2'}})
```

```py
if "a" in my_dic["key1"] and "b" in my_dic["key1"]:
    print("Exists")
if "a-foo" in my_dic["key1"] and "b-foo" in my_dic["key1"]:
    print("Exists")
if "a-bar" in my_dic["key1"] and "b-bar" in my_dic["key1"]:
    print("Exists")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This generalizes nicely to N entries.

```py
valuepairs = (("a", "b"), ("a-foo", "b-foo"), ("a-bar", "b-bar"))
if any(all(key in my_dic["key1"] for key in pair) for pair in valuepairs):
    print("Exists")
```

You can also generate the value pairs lazily like this:

```py
roots = ("a", "b")
extensions = ("", "-foo", "-bar")
valuepairs = ((root + extension for root in roots) for extension in extensions)
```

Comment: I might be reading the question differently, but I think it's just as important that `valuepairs` itself can be generated with `valuepairs = [("a" + sfx, "b"+sfx) for sfx in suffixes]` for some arbitrary list of suffixes, in this case `suffixes = ["", "-foo", "-bar"]`.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```py
if (
    ("a" in my_dic["key1"] and "b" in my_dic["key1"])
    or ("a-foo" in my_dic["key1"] and "b-foo" in my_dic["key1"])
    or ("a-bar" in my_dic["key1"] and "b-bar" in my_dic["key1"])
):
    print("Exists")
```

And in general:

```py
subsets: list[set[str]] = [{"a", "b"}, {"a-foo", "b-foo"}, {"a-bar", "b-bar"}]
if any(subset.issubset(my_dic["key1"]) for subset in subsets):
    print("Exists")
```